# Lightning Design System component for dashed separator line?

Tags: slds

Is there a Lightning Design Component that will generate a dashed separator line like what you see for the Next Steps and Past Activities sections in the standard Opportunity record page?
[image: Next Steps and Past Activities]

(I don't need the More Steps button, I just want the dashed separator line immediately after the section text)

I've looked at the CSS on a typical page and I see classes like `slds-section__title-action slds-align-middle slds-truncate` but when I try to use these in my custom component, I don't get anything like what I see in the screnshot.

I've searched using various terms like separator, header, dashed, etc but haven't found anything applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know of anything that applies a border other than the class `slds-border_*` (top, bottom, left, right)

you can specify it to be dotted throught css though:

Example:

```
<lightning:input class="slds-border_top" .... />
```

CSS

```
.THIS.slds-border_top{
    border-top : 1px dotted;
}
```

or, if you want to add some dots after some text

component:

```
<div class="dots-here">Something</div>
```

Style:

```
.THIS.dots-here:after {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted;
    content: '';
    flex: 1;
}

.THIS.dots-here{
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
}
```

But nothing OOTB to my knowledge.